# SF Pro Display Font not working in SwiftUI View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fonts, swiftui

Have been trying to implement `SF Pro Display` font in `SwiftUI` but not working! I have copied the files in Xcode and also in the `info.plist` file. Other fonts work but `SF Pro Display` not working. Can anyone help?

```
[UPDATE: No need to import SF Fonts in Xcode. Xcode uses SF Pro Display Fonts by default]
```

The extension:

```
extension Font {

struct SF {
    static func regular(size: CGFloat) -> Font {
        .custom("SF-Pro-Display-Regular", size: size)
    }
    
    static func light(size: CGFloat) -> Font {
        .custom("SF-Pro-Display-Light", size: size)
    }
    
    static func medium(size: CGFloat) -> Font {
        .custom("SF-Pro-Display-Medium", size: size)
    }
}
```

In SwiftUI

```
Text("81%")
  .font(Font.SF.medium(size: 55))
  .shadow(radius: 10, y: 5)
```

[Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgLLS.png)

[Fonts in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9USEn.png)

[SwiftUI Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V7YU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found somewhere long time ago, that it needs the "PostScript name" that you can find in Font Book, and as far as I understand from documentation, you do not need to import it in .plist.

[font book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWck3.png)

Comment: May only work temporarily. Apple discourages this and made Font.system API for this purpose.